# Closing Animation Issue in React Drawer Component with Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

In my react project in which I also used tailwind CSS, I implemented the functionality to open the Drawer after clicking the icon in the menu.

The problem is that the closing animation is lost after my implementation (the opening animation remains as it should be).

Let's take a look at the component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {PlusCircleIcon} from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import AddRecordTabs from "../record/AddRecordTabs";
import {Drawer} from "@material-tailwind/react";

const Menu = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const openDrawer = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    const closeDrawer = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (open) {
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        }
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-white z-50 border-t-1 border-green-900">
            <div className="h-[60px] flex items-center justify-between">

                <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-grow">
                    <Link onClick={openDrawer}>
                        <PlusCircleIcon color="green" className="w-12 h-12" strokeWidth={2} />
                    </Link>
                </div>

            </div>
            
            {open && (
                <>
                    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-sm" onClick={() => { closeDrawer(); }}></div>
                    <div>
                        <Drawer
                            placement="bottom"
                            open={open}
                            onClose={() => closeDrawer()}
                            size={window.innerHeight * 0.9}
                            className="pt-2 bg-green-50 border-t-1 border-green-900 rounded-t-[10px]"
                        >
                            <div className=" h-full overflow-y-auto">
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                                    <AddRecordTabs closeDrawer={closeDrawer} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Drawer>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

We don't need to worry about the `AddRecordsTabs` component and this passed value, because it's basically just passed functionality to close the Drawer.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider removing the conditional rendering around the `<Drawer>`. This completely removes the `<Drawer>` DOM from the page before any animations happen.

See [this live implementation on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-npqpjg?file=src%2FApp.jsx).